# How to set QPlainTextEdit verticalScrollBar to maximum?

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Consider this mcve:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class Foo(QPlainTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_P:
            self.appendPlainText(f"New line")
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


class FooWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        m = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Debug")
        action = QAction("Baz", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.bar)
        action.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        m.addAction(action)

        self.obj = Foo()
        self.obj.setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)

        for i in range(20):
            self.obj.appendPlainText(f"Line_{i}" * 10)

        self.obj_dock = QDockWidget('Console', self)
        self.obj_dock.setWidget(self.obj)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.obj_dock)

    def bar(self):
        self.obj.appendPlainText(f"New line from menu action")

    def showEvent(self, event):
        bar = self.obj.verticalScrollBar()
        bar.setValue(bar.maximum())
        print(f"2) showEvent {now()}")


def now():
    return datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FooWindow()
    print(f"1) before show {now()}")
    ex.show()
    print(f"3) after show {now()}")

    # ex.obj.ensureCursorVisible()
    bar = ex.obj.horizontalScrollBar()
    bar.setValue(bar.minimum())
    bar = ex.obj.verticalScrollBar()
    bar.setValue(bar.maximum())

    print(f"4) manual bar.setValue {now()}")

    # timer = QTimer()
    # timer.setInterval(10)
    # timer.setSingleShot(True)
    # def set_scrollbar_at_maximum():
    #     bar = ex.obj.verticalScrollBar()
    #     bar.setValue(ex.obj.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
    #     print(f"5) bar.setValue from timer {now()}")
    # timer.timeout.connect(set_scrollbar_at_maximum)
    # timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'd like to view the last lines added without having to scroll the vertical bar down manually. Calling `bar.setValue(ex.obj.verticalScrollBar().maximum())` after either `ex.show()` or `def showEvent(self, event):` don't work, ie:

[image: showcase]

Thing is, unless I scroll the vertical bar down manually or I set the value using a single-shot timer the last added lines won't be visible.

I'd like to know why my above snippet isn't working properly and I'd like to know a best alternative to these single-shot timers with random little intervals... Said otherwise, what's the proper place that will guarantee the child widgets will be painted properly after using functions such as setValue. This stuff is pretty confusing, one would expect the showEvent to be a proper place to do so... but it's not :/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to use single-shot timers to guarantee the widgets will be painted properly, it seems overriding `QMainWindow::event` is a good choice, here's a possible solution to the problem:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class Foo(QPlainTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_P:
            self.appendPlainText(f"New line")
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


class FooWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        m = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Debug")
        action = QAction("Baz", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.bar)
        action.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        m.addAction(action)

        self.obj = Foo()
        self.obj.setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)

        for i in range(20):
            self.obj.appendPlainText(f"Line_{i}" * 10)

        self.obj_dock = QDockWidget('Console', self)
        self.obj_dock.setWidget(self.obj)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.obj_dock)
        self.window_shown = False

    def bar(self):
        self.obj.appendPlainText(f"New line from menu action")

    def update_widgets(self):
        if self.window_shown:
            return

        bar = ex.obj.horizontalScrollBar()
        bar.setValue(bar.minimum())
        bar = self.obj.verticalScrollBar()
        bar.setValue(bar.maximum())
        self.window_shown = True

    def event(self, ev):
        ret_value = super().event(ev)

        if ev.type() == QEvent.Paint:
            self.update_widgets()

        return ret_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FooWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```